# Soul's underline misses text produced by a macro

Tags: macros, soul

The macro `ul` provided by `soul` works great, allowing linebreaks within an underlined text block. It even supports macros - if they were registered with `soulregister`.

But if these registered macros produce text *on their own*, it isn't underlined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\one}[1]{\ul{#1}}
\newcommand{\two}[1]{not underlined #1}

\soulregister{\two}{1}

\begin{document}
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
\end{document}
```

[image: "not underlined" isn't underlined]

How can I make sure this text is underlined correctly?

Comment: It's not math-mode that's causing the problems.  Replace your math content with any text, you'll still have the same effect.

Comment: Oops - I thought I had checked that, thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Can someone enlighten me please - if you're just underlining, why use `soul` and not `ulem`?

Comment: @ChrisH: Because I didn't think of it. `ulem` seems to handle this perfectly - thanks!

Comment: Good news then - I hadn't heard of `soul` so I was curious.

Comment: @ChrisH: Hopefully we will both get some enlightenment once there are answers to [List of Underlining Packages - Pros and Cons](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons).

Comment: I've thrown my 2p's worth in there as well - an interesting discussion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For registered commands, `soul` will split up the string, turning it basically into

```
\ul{first part}\command{\ul{second part}}
```

So if `\command` produces any text, this will end up outside of the scope of `soul`'s scanner. To solve this you can pre-expand the string before feeding it to `soul`:

```
\newcommand{\one}[1]{\protected@edef\@tempa{#1}\ul\@tempa}
```

EDIT: Another possibility would be to register your `\two` command with identifier `7` instead of `1`, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139500/7674).

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't tied into `soul` for some other reason, then a modified `\xblackout` of the `censor` package might suffice for this task.

EDITED to fix problem with line breaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.3ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\newlength\x
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{\censorrule{\widthofpbox{#1}}%
  \setlength{\x}{\widthofpbox{#1}}%
  \hspace{-\x}%
  #1}
\long\def\xblackout#1{\rule{0ex}{0ex}%
  \def~{-}%
  \def\@justpar{F}%
  \def\@justperiod{F}%
  \def\@justspace{F}%
  \protected@edef\save@arg{#1}%
  \expandafter\xcensor@Block\save@arg\stringend%
  \let~\sv@tilde%
 }
\makeatother
\newcommand{\one}[1]{\xblackout{#1}}
\newcommand{\two}[1]{not underlined #1}
%\soulregister{\two}{1}
\begin{document}
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
test1 \one{test2 \two{test3}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a quite interesting use of `censor`. However, it does seem to have problems with line breaking: Sometimes, a word breaks to a new line, but the underline stays in the previous line.

Comment: @fefrei Hmm. I can now see how that would happen, if the breaking phrase were part of the embedded macro. Noting that significant deficiency, shall I remove the answer?

Comment: Of course, that's up to you - but still, the answer may be useful in some circumstances.

Comment: @fefrei  Fixed the `censor` approach to work with line breaks (also using a `\protected@edef`).

Comment: @fefrei  If interested, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons/126358#126358 for an improved version of this approach, which leaves a gap around descenders, and does math underlining, too.