# Controling underline depth in math mode

Tags: math-mode, text-decorations, ulem

I use the `ulem` package to control the depth of underlines by setting

```
\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1pt}
```

This works fine outside math mode. However, when using `\uline` inside math mode, I seem to lose control over the underline depth. (Adding `\smash` doesn't really solve the problem either.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt} % add space between paragraphs for illustration

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1pt} 
\uline{normal text} $\uline{f(x)=y}$

\uline{normal text} $\uline{\smash{f(x)=y}}$

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{10pt}
\uline{normal text} $\uline{f(x)=y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to "regain control" over underline depth within math mode. If such control is not possible with the `ulem` package (I also tried with `soul`, which didn't work), are there other packages that can achieve the purpose of making the depth of underlines uniform both inside and outside math mode?

Comment: do you want to underline the entire expression or subterms? If the former you can simply do `\uline{normal text} \uline{$f(x)=y$}` and it seems to obey the parameter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know that `\uline{$<math content>$}` works. But I'm underlining texts in the `game` environment provided by Martin Osborne's [`sgame`](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/sgame.pdf) package, in which the cells in a matrix is automatically set in math mode. So when I do use `\uline` in that environment, it would be as if I'm using `$\uline{...}$`.

Comment: well you can do `$\mbox{\uline{$....$}}$`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons/126358#126358 where the censor package has been hacked to permit underlining in math mode.  You can set the underrule depth and the underrule thickness.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks! `\mbox` works, nice and easy :)

Comment: As a follow-up on my prior comment, `\xblackout{abc} $\mblackout[1pt]{y = x^2}$` seems to align the math underline and text underline, regardless of descenders in the math mode.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: So in general, is it right that if I set `\censorruledepth=<length>`, then I'll just have to use the optional argument `[<length>]` with `\mblackout` to align the underlines in the two modes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  `$\mbox{\uline{$....$}}$` if you want to underline a subterm of the math with `ulem` text settings.

Answer (score 5):

This is an extension to [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133247/16967):

- It defines `\mathuline` that can be used in math mode to get the text mode version of `\uline`, using David's trick. Additionally `\mathpalette` is used to get the correct math style.
- [Optional] `\uline` is redefined to use `\mathuline` in math mode instead of the default `\underline`. But beware, if you have larger symbols and formulas with larger depth (e.g. `\int`, `\frac`), then the line will cross the formula.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\saved@uline}{}
\let\saved@uline\uline

\newcommand*{\mathuline}{%
  \mathpalette{\math@uline\saved@uline}%
}
\newcommand*{\math@uline}[3]{%
  % #1: ulem command
  % #2: math style
  % #3: contents
  \mbox{#1{$#2#3\m@th$}}%
}

% optional
\renewcommand*{\uline}{%
  \relax  
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mathuline
  \else
    \expandafter\saved@uline
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\uline{normal text} $\uline{f(x)=y}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]