# Use Tikz to draw underlines

Tags: tikz-pgf, ulem

The following MWE contains the definition of a custom macro for colored underlines with the `ulem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}


\newcommand{\muline}{\bgroup\markoverwith
{\textcolor{red}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}

\begin{document}
\muline{This is some very very very very long text that does not fit in a single line but needs two.}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use TikZ to draw the underline?

What I have in mind is the possibility to use something like `\draw(start)--(end);` instead of the `rule` command.

Of course it is required that the underline works for multi-line texts as the `ulem` underline does.

Comment: Underlines are ugly. But related [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex) and [List of Underlining Packages - Pros and Cons](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons)

Comment: Is this just a `tikz` exercise or is there another motivator as to why `ulem` or other approaches are inadequate?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Because I need the powerful decoration system of TikZ to customize the underlines and create various effects. The specific use case is to produce slides for children, by the way.

Comment: @percusse that question solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Jansen: Oppss, it seems that I have become more powerful than I was aware of.  I did not know that my vote to close would close this question. If you want it reopened, please let me know and I will try to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @PeterGrill I managed to adapt those solutions to my needs, so this can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterGrill: From a couple of months or so, casting a close vote in a question in which you have a gold badge in one of the tags, it closes the question immediately.