# Automatic new line to my macro

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I've created that new macro:

```
\newcommand{\undbf}[1] {\textbf{\underline{\smash{#1}}}}
```

To get underline closer to letters but, for instance with this code:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\newcommand{\undbf}[1] {\textbf{\underline{\smash{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\undbf{StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange, StackExchange,}
\end{document}
```

I've not got line-breaking automatically; I mean:

[image]

And I would like could underline text in that way but have got automatic new lines. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Have a look at the `soul` or `ulem` package.

Comment: But then I don't get underlines closer to letters. \smash doesn't work apparently.

Comment: `\smash` is wrong anyway

Comment: My answer here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons/126358#126358, may or may not help.