# Strange behaviour of ulem?

Tags: bold, ulem

I know, it's ugly and seems stupid, but I need to redefine like that. I try a lot of things (`\edef`, `\expandafter`...) Nothing seems to work. No break line.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\def\texteSouligne#1{\uline{#1}}
\def\texteGras#1{{\textbf{#1}}}
\def\texteItalique#1{{\it #1}}

\begin{document}
Voici du texte \texteSouligne{souligné \texteItalique{et eded  e defn même temps italique bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla.}}

Voici du texte \texteSouligne{souligné \texteGras{et en même bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla temps gras.}}

\texteSouligne{Voici du texte souligné,  bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla \texteGras{en gras \texteItalique{et en même temps italique.}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You say that you want to redefine `ulem` macros. 1st question: Why? 2nd question: What did you do? Third question: Why using `\it` which is outdated?. And I doubt that `ulem` macros are expandable to use it with `\edef`

Comment: Related to underlining: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons

Comment: no related, I've already read this Q/A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a restriction of package `ulem`. From its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.pdf), section "3 Complications":

> One important incompatibility with braces and macro replacement: **All
>   the text in braces or coming from a macro is typeset in a box** (as if
>   in `\mbox`). Consequently, braces will suppress stretching and
>   line-breaking in the text they enclose.

### Package `soul`

The example from the question can be typeset with package `soul`. It has its own limitations, see its [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul). The following example uses package `soulutf8` to add UTF-8 support for 8-bit TeX engines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\newcommand{\texteSouligne}[1]{\ul{#1}}
\newcommand{\texteGras}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\texteItalique}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\soulregister{\texteGras}{1}
\soulregister{\texteItalique}{1}

\begin{document}

Voici du texte \texteSouligne{souligné \texteItalique{et eded  e defn même
temps italique bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla.}}

Voici du texte \texteSouligne{souligné \texteGras{et en même bla blabla
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla temps gras.}}

\texteSouligne{Voici du texte souligné,  bla bla blabla bla blabla bla
blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla \texteGras{en gras
\texteItalique{et en même temps italique.}}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, I have tried soul package but not soulutf8.