# Blackout censor macro capable of handling italic and bold fonts

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, spacing, programming, underline

In the following [TeX stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126358/252598), the author provides an excellent `\blackout` macro that produces very aesthetically pleasing underline effect.

However, this macro does not work well with any bold or italic text. In particular, instead of

```
\blackout{This should be \textbf{bold} and \textit{italic}}
```

which fails with

```
! Argument of \textbf  has an extra }.
```

one has to use

```
\blackout{This should be} \textbf{\blackout{bold}} \blackout{and} \textit{\blackout{italic}}}
```

which is more verbose. Is there a way to adjust the definition of `\blackout` to handle this, or perhaps a way how to automatically apply `\blackout` to every word in the sentence, thereby automatically producing the more verbose version?

EDIT: I've figured out that using `\bfseries ... \mdseries` instead of `\textbf{...}` and `\itshape ... \upshape` instead of `\textit{...}` fixes the problem. I'd still like to understand why though, and if the original `\blackout` macro could be modified to work with `\textbf{} / \textit{}`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on a revamped version of `censor` which uses token cycles to process the argument to `\blackout` and `\xblackout`.  It can, at least, digest macros.  There are still issues, as explained in the new manual, but in a case like the OP describes, it works just fine.

This will also allow alternate syntax of `\blackoutenv ... \endblackoutenv`.  Likewise for `\xblackoutenv`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor-PROVISIONAL}
\begin{document}
This should be \textbf{bold} and \textit{italic}

\blackout{This should be \textbf{bold} and \textit{italic}}

\xblackout{This should be \textbf{bold} and \textit{italic}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another example that highlights usage with expandable macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor-PROVISIONAL}
\begin{document}
Today's date is \today. Let it be great.

\blackout{Today's date is \today. Let it be great.}

\blackout{Today's date is \expanded{\today}. Let it be great.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am hoping to release it soon, but in the meantime, I will post a provisional version.

Here is `censor-PROVISIONAL.sty`

```
% censor.sty
\def\censorversionnumber{4.0}
\ProvidesPackage{censor-PROVISIONAL}
[2021/09/14 \censorversionnumber
 Provides capability for redaction of sensitive information]

%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the 
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3 
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX 
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Steven B. Segletes.

% VERSION:
% 1.00 - Initial release
% 2.00 - Added \blackout
% 2.10 - Allowed \blackout to cross paragraph boundaries with use of
%        \bpar. Stopped censoring periods, in order to preserve
%        end-of-sentence spacing, which differs from inter-word spacing.
% 3.00 - \censorbox introduced to handle figures, tables, etc.
% 3.10 - Made \blackout work with \par in argument.  Introduced 
%        \xblackout
% 3.20 - Specify depth/height of censor rule.  Introduced \def\censordot{}
% 3.21 - Fixed bug regarding \xblackout rules remaining after a
%        \StopCensoring
% 3.22 - changed `\if to \ifx in definition of \bl@t, to handle macros like \%
% 4.0  - Recast \blackout and \xblackout in terms of tokcycle environments
%      - Introduced \blackoutenv...\endblackoutenv and 
%        \xblackoutenv...\endxblackoutenv
\usepackage{pbox}

\newlength\censorruledepth
\newlength\censorruleheight

\censorruledepth=-0.3ex% -0.3ex DEFAULT
\censorruleheight=2.1ex%  2.1ex DEFAULT
\def\censordot{\censor{.}}% versus \def\censordot{ }%

\newcommand\censorrule[1]{\protect\rule[\censorruledepth]{#1}{\censorruleheight}}

\newcommand\censor{\@ifstar{\@cenlen}{\@cenword}}
  \newcommand\@cenlen[1]{\censorrule{#1 ex}}
  \newcommand\@cenword[1]{\censorrule{\widthofpbox{#1}}}

\newcommand\un@censor{\@ifstar{\un@cenlen}{\un@cenword}}
  \newcommand\un@cenlen[1]{\protect\underline{\hspace{#1 ex}}}
  \newcommand\un@cenword[1]{#1}

\newcommand\StopCensoring{%
           \let\censor\un@censor%
           \let\censorbox\un@censorbox%
           \renewcommand\censpace{ }%
}
\newcommand\RestartCensoring{%
           \renewcommand\censor{\@ifstar{\@cenlen}{\@cenword}}%
           \renewcommand\censorbox{\@ifstar{\censor@dim}{\censor@box}}%
           \let\censpace\sv@censpace%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021/03/10]


\def\@dump#1{\addcytoks[1]{\expandafter\censor\expandafter{#1}}\def#1{}}
\def\@append#1#2{\tc@defx#1{#1#2}}

\def\spacelap{0.6ex}
\def\censpace{\rlap{\censorrule{\spacelap}} \llap{\censorrule{\spacelap}}}
\let\sv@censpace\censpace

\long\def\blackout#1{\blackoutenv#1\endblackoutenv}
\long\def\xblackout#1{\xblackoutenv#1\endxblackoutenv}

\newif\ifexpandarg

\xtokcycleenvironment\xblackoutenv
  {\ifx.##1\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks[1]{\censordot}\else
    \@append\censored@word{##1}%
    \tcpeek\@next\ifx\@next\@tcEscapeptr\@dump\censored@word\fi\fi}
  {\tctestifcon\ifexpandarg{\expandafter\processtoks\expandafter{\expanded{##1}}}%
    {\processtoks{##1}}\@dump\censored@word\expandargfalse}
  {\@dump\censored@word\tctestifx{~##1}{\@append\censored@word{##1}}%
    {\tctestifx{\expanded##1}{\expandargtrue}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
  {\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks{\censpace}}
  {\def\censored@word{}}
  {\@dump\censored@word}
\xtokcycleenvironment\blackoutenv
  {\ifx.##1\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks[1]{\censordot}\else
    \@append\censored@word{##1}%
    \tcpeek\@next\ifx\@next\@tcEscapeptr\@dump\censored@word\fi\fi}
  {\tctestifcon\ifexpandarg{\expandafter\processtoks\expandafter{\expanded{##1}}}%
    {\processtoks{##1}}\@dump\censored@word\expandargfalse}
  {\@dump\censored@word\tctestifx{~##1}{\@append\censored@word{##1}}%
    {\tctestifx{\expanded##1}{\expandargtrue}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
  {\@dump\censored@word\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\def\censored@word{}}
  {\@dump\censored@word}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\censorbox{\@ifstar{\censor@dim}{\censor@box}}
  \newcommand\censor@dim[4][]{{#1%
                      \rule[-#4\baselineskip]{#2ex}{#3\baselineskip}}}
  \newcommand\censor@box[2][]{#1\setbox0\hbox{#2}%
                      \rule[-\the\dp0]{\the\wd0}{\the\ht0+\the\dp0}}

\newcommand\un@censorbox{\@ifstar{\un@censor@dim}{\un@censor@box}}
  \newcommand\un@censor@dim[4][]{{#1%
                      \fbox{\rule[-#4\baselineskip]{0ex}{#3\baselineskip}
                      \rule{#2ex}{0ex}}}}
  \newcommand\un@censor@box[2][]{#1#2}

% NOTE: A \protect\censorbox{} MAY BE REQUIRED INSIDE SOME ENVIRONMENTS
\endinput
```

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP was disappointed that the `censor` hack that worked in [List of Underlining Packages - Pros and Cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons/126358#126358) no longer seems to work with this provisional package.  An investigation reveals that what doesn't work isn't my `censor` hack, but my `lipsum` hack (to get expanded lipsum text) in that answer.  The essential `censor` hack still works in this context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor-PROVISIONAL}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\censorruledepth=-.25ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\newlength\maxkern
\setlength{\maxkern}{.1ex}
\newlength\nextcharwidth
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{%
  \setlength{\nextcharwidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \censorrule{\nextcharwidth}%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \color{white}%
  \kern -.5\maxkern #1\kern .5\maxkern%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \kern -\maxkern #1\kern \maxkern%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \kern .5\maxkern #1\kern -.5\maxkern%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \kern \maxkern #1\kern -\maxkern%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \color{black}%
  #1{}}
\begin{document}
Thiys, should pe \textbf{bold} ang \textit{italic}!

\blackout{Thiys, should pe \textbf{bold} ang \textit{italic}!}

\xblackout{Thiys, should pe \textbf{bold} ang \textit{italic}!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Steven, thank you for the answer and all your work on TeX! I have been able to use this new version of the package, however - looks like the \censor@Block is no longer defined, which makes the underline version of `\blackout` from the [your linked answer from 8 years ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126358/252598) no longer work with the new censor package. Any advice on how the underline version of `blackout` should be modified?

Comment: @UnderlineApprentice You are correct that a hack such as the one you referenced would no longer be applicable, wince the whole underlying approach of censor is being revamped.  I will have a look, but am not hopeful for compatibility

Comment: @UnderlineApprentice A preliminary look show that what has broken is my access to `\singlelipsum`, a hack of the lipsum package.  The censor modifications seem to work with this revised package.

Comment: @UnderlineApprentice Please see my **SUPPLEMENT**.

Comment: This works great! My mistake was that I was also redefining `\long\def\blackout`, which still referenced `\censor@Block`, whereas I should be just using `\blackout` from the `censor-PROVISIONAL` and only redefine `@cenword`.

I still have some minor problems trying to get this to play well with `microtype` on `\blackout` sentences that span multiple lines in the tex source, but I think that's a different question :)