# Error adapting Steven B. Segletes Revised Solution to use \xblackout for breaking underline with Glossary \gls

Tags: underline, glossary

I'm attempting to adapt `Segletes`'s **Revised Solution** in [List of Underlining Packages - Pros and Cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons) that employs `alexwlchan`'s [Four ways to underline text in LATEX](https://alexwlchan.net/2017/10/latex-underlines/) in order to re-create `alexwlchan`'s '*really nice underline*' macro that **also** *wraps at the end of the line*.

I found that `Segletes`'s rendition of the `\xblackout` macro works nicely to create `alexwlchan`'s version of the '*really nice underline*' macro that ***also*** wraps at the end of the line. Nice.

I've been able to apply `Segletes`'s revised `\xblackout` macro to a few different text styles, but I'm having trouble applying it to the Glossary `\gls` macro, as in `\xblackout{\gls[hyper=true]{LED}}`.

I've included an MWE that essentially duplicates `Segletes`'s MWE that appears in the [List of Underlining Packages - Pros and Cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons) with the necessary code added to implement a Glossary. The next-to-last line of code in the MWE: `\xblackout{\gls[hyper=true]{LED}}` is where the LaTeX error `Missing \endcsname inserted.` occurs.

Note: I've essentially left all of `Segletes` **Revised Solution** in the MWE intact as a way to show that *his* code works, *except* for *my* next-to-last line of code for the glossary where the only LaTeX error occurs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
% Adapted from Steven B. Segletes post on Aug 1, 2013 at 12:51:
% "List of Underlining Packages - Pros and Cons"
% at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons
% Adapted from alexwlchan's "Four ways to underline text in LATEX"
% at https://alexwlchan.net/2017/10/latex-underlines/

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel,lipsum}

% Added
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\censorruledepth=-.25ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\newlength\maxkern
\setlength{\maxkern}{.14ex}
\newlength\nextcharwidth
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{%
  \setlength{\nextcharwidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \censorrule{\nextcharwidth}%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \color{white}%
  \kern -.5\maxkern #1\kern .5\maxkern%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \kern -\maxkern #1\kern \maxkern%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \kern .5\maxkern #1\kern -.5\maxkern%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \kern \maxkern #1\kern -\maxkern%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  \color{black}%
  #1}
\let\sv@cenword\@cenword
\newcommand\m@cenword[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackengine{\mcensorruledepth}{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
    {\rule{\widthof{$\SavedStyle#1$}}{\the\censorruleheight}}{U}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\newcommand\mblackout[2][\dp\strutbox]{%
  \let\@cenword\m@cenword%
  \def\mcensorruledepth{#1}%
  \blackout{#2}%
  \let\@cenword\sv@cenword%
}
\newcommand\mcensor[2][\dp\strutbox]{%
  \let\@cenword\m@cenword%
  \def\mcensorruledepth{#1}%
  \censor{#2}%
  \let\@cenword\sv@cenword%
}
\makeatother

% Added
\newglossaryentry{LED}
{
  name={LED},
  description={light emitting diode},
  first={\glsentrydesc{LED} (\glsentrytext{LED})},
  plural={LEDs},
  descriptionplural={light emitting diodes},
  firstplural={\glsentrydescplural{LED} (\glsentryplural{LED})}
} 

\begin{document}
\blackout{This is a great test today}

{\raggedright\xblackout{This is a great test today}}

% Modified
\[ \mblackout{y = A x^2} + Bx + \mblackout{C} \]
% \[ \mblackout{y = A x^{2}} + Bx + \mblackout{C} \]

% Modified
\[ \mblackout[.3ex]{y = \frac{a^3 + b^2 + c}{d_3}}\]
% \[ \mblackout[.3ex]{y = \frac{a^{3} + b^{2} + c}{d_{3}}}\]

\[ \mcensor[3ex]{y = \frac{a^{3} + b^{2} + c}{d_{3}}}\]

\xblackout{Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel 
  justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum 
fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus 
eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. 
Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.} \par \vspace{1cm}

% Added
\uline{\gls[hyper=true]{LED}} \par \vspace{1cm}
\uline{\gls[hyper=true]{LED}} \par \vspace{1cm}

% Error: Missing \endcsname inserted.
\xblackout{\gls[hyper=true]{LED}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A problem here is that neither `\gls` nor `\xblackout` are expandable, so this poses a big hurdle.

Comment: You might be able to use an expandable macro, such as `\glsentrytext` by way of `\expandafter\xblackout\expandafter{\expanded{\glsentrytext{LED}}}`.  However, any hyperlinks would be lost by `\glsentrytext`.